# Running email.php from .html page?

Tags: php, html

I am building this website that will have both a search bar and a contact form on every one of its pages. So I will need to run a couple simple scripts on an infinite number of pages. How do I run email.php and search.php from the .html page? Do i need to make all of my pages .php?

Answer (score 0):

From a ***HTML*** page you can run a `.php` file by sending a [***AJAX***](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) request.

You will have to use `JS/JQuery.` Since you want to run the php file on many pages, It would be advisable that you put your `AJAX` request ina a file and include it on all pages where required.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use php.  I would suggest creating a page called contact.php and put your form on that page.  then on every page you write use a function in php called include or require and call that page.  for example:

whateverPage.php

```
 <?php

 include('contact.php');

 //rest of your page

 ?>
```

contact.php

```
<script>
 //some jquery stuff involving ajax 
 //and an event handler to handle the click of the submit button.
 </script>

 <form id='contact' action='#' method='POST'>
  Name:<input type='text' id='name' name='name'>
 <input type='button' id='sub' value='submit'>
```

on this page you will need to include some jquery that will fire off an ajax call to another page let's say (contactProcessor.php) that will handle whatever you want to do with form data.

dont forget to include a link to the jquery files at the top of contact.php